# How to add a Kafka client to a Rails Docker deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka

We have a Rails app that we deploy in a Docker environment (currently ECS but moving to Kubernetes). We are adding Kafka to our architecture, using [Amazon's managed Kafka service](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/).

What's the best way to add the Kafka consumer library to our Rails app? We are using [rdkafka-ruby](https://github.com/appsignal/rdkafka-ruby), but should we:

- Add it to our Rails app container, or
- Deploy it as a separate container?

Answer (score 1):

According to [rdkafka](https://github.com/appsignal/rdkafka-ruby) intro:

> This gem only provides a high-level Kafka consumer

As for service, it's recommended to use `kafka` service in separate instances. Since you are going to use [Amazon MSK](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/) as a `kafka` service, it seems ok to add the `rdkafka` gem into your app.

P.S. That's how Xing [used](https://tech.xing.com/asynchronous-state-replication-9e504aeac0de) [rdkafka-ruby](https://github.com/appsignal/rdkafka-ruby) for [migrate from transactions to streams](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/event-streams-kafka/)

Answer (score 0):

@DavidHam how did you late implement rd-kafka in your rails app as a gem. Having some troubles doing that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33857248)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).